# Roomba robot vacuum for dealing with cat hair?

Tags: cats, cleaning, senior-pet

Our cats shed lots of hair, so I spend a significant amount of time with a broom just picking up hair. This literally destroys my back.

So I was thinking of buying one of those robot vacuums that just move around the house, like a Roomba. It looks something [like this](https://assets.rbl.ms/551951/640x364.jpg).

My question: will this actually help? The reason I ask is that my cats are always shedding, so does that mean that the vacuum will always be on and moving from place to place?

What else do you recommend? I also bought a swiffer, but I haven't used it yet.

Comment: There are vast differences in the quality of those robots and their performance depends on different factors. What kind of flooring do you have? How long is the hair of your cats? How many obstacles like furniture, decorations and raised doorsteps between rooms do you have at home?

Comment: Roombas come on on a timer and move until they've sufficiently covered all available floor area or until their battery is low, then they return to their dock to charge. They work slowly but surely and are often moving. My parents have one in a large house with three dogs and it is effective in the long run.

Comment: A swiffer is more for spot cleaning. I recently bought a Shark HV382 for manual regular cleaning of my carpets and hard floors (I have two longhair cats) and its perfect because: 1) it is maneuverable and fits in tight places, 2) it vacuums to the very edge of the vacuum head, 3) it detaches from the head quickly with a foot pedal for detail vacuuming, 4) it has very effective attachments for furniture, 5) it's bagless, and 6) it's easy to clear jams. Downside is its back heavy and can't stand on its own. But imho it's a must have for sheddy pet owners.

Comment: Re the roomba it works at my parents place but I never got one for my apartment because I keep too many things on the floor 

Comment: One last thing: for years I thought the swiffer wetjet was the best thing since sliced bread. Then I bought a plain old mop with a bucket. Far superior in every way except the closet space it takes up.

Comment: Got wooden floors, I presume? Not carpet? Roomba isn’t guaranteed to cover every inch of floor (there are other ones that do, but they’re more expensive). I’ve had a roomba and it was inclined to get stuck under my sofa or chew up any newspaper it found but it did the job (short carpets, 3 good sized rooms, no furry animals or stairs). You’d need to empty it regularly, though.

Comment: Fair warning if your cats are prone to vomit or have hairballs, or occasionally poop outside the litterbox, the Roomba can make that situation so, SO much worse.  (Google 'Roomba dog poo'... if you dare).

Answer (score -2):

A robot vacuum could be very dangerous. I had a cat once that enjoyed having a vacuum run over his fur. Picking up the hairs before they fall off! But the cat has to enjoy it, and you have to use the lowest setting and be very careful not to pull the skin which is very loose, into the machine.
I can see your cats taking a great interest in a robot machine, and they could easily flip it over and injure or electrocute themselves. Either that Or they'll leave home.